# Using Transaction and Add selected checksbox items with parameters loop error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

[image]

I am using Transaction While Using the 3 different database table insert the value.

When ı select the checkboxs, it insert just one item on database.

Multiple Transaction  Insert with Parameters loop error

```
for (int i = 0; i < TurAltKatSecilenler.Length; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(TurAltKatSecilenler[i]);
                cmdTurAlt.Parameters.Clear();
                cmdTurAlt.Parameters.Add("AltKategoriID", TurAltKatSecilenler[i]);
                cmdTurAlt.Parameters.Add("AnaKategoriID", dlTurAnaKategori.SelectedValue);

            }

cmdTurAlt .Transaction = sqlTrans;

 try{ cmdTurAlt.ExecuteNonQuery(); sqlTrans.Commit();}

 catch (Exception hata){  sqlTrans.Rollback();  }
```

Comment: Could you please show your full code?

Comment: In your loop you clear all parameters all the time so only the last iteration of the loop remains; you cannot do multiple inserts with one statement. You need to open the transaction, execute an insert or each checkbox and commit after that

Comment: I am using   .Parameters.Clear() for that

Comment: You clear them before you execute them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** You are executing the command outside the `for - loop` so it would only excute the insert into statement with last parameters.

**Solution :** need to move the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method inside `for - loop`.

Try This:

```
try
{ 
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < TurAltKatSecilenler.Length; i++)
    {
        msg.Append(TurAltKatSecilenler[i].ToString()+Environment.NewLine);          
        cmdTurAlt.Parameters.Add("AltKategoriID",TurAltKatSecilenler[i]);
        cmdTurAlt.Parameters.Add("AnaKategoriID",dlTurAnaKategori.SelectedValue);
        cmdTurAlt.Transaction = sqlTrans;    
        cmdTurAlt.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        sqlTrans.Commit();
        cmdTurAlt.Parameters.Clear();
    }
    Response.Write(msg);
}
```

Comment: @neon: sorry i didnt get you? could you please explain me if you are facing any problem.

Comment: yes it is working but , while insert the database ID different SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tblTur') , it gives different Transaction id  , I have not any id problem before while put the code

Comment: @neon:why do you want to use `Response.Write()` if not required please remove this, and also clear the parameters at the end.check my edited answer.